# JSP: String to Date Format

Tags: jsp

I need to convert a string (extracted from SQL table) to a date format in JSP. I did this:

```
String PeerdateNtime="Wednesday, February 6, 2013 10:11:00 PM"; //this is the sample string
SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("E, M d, yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa");
Date newPeerdateNtime = formater.parse(PeerdateNtime);
```

However, there is something wrong and I could not get the date. Is there something I did wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `"EEE, MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss aa"`

Note the `hh` to indicate the 12-hour clock, vs. `HH` for the 24-hour clock.

The *numbers* of formatting characters matter, since they dictate whether the string interpreted is the long or short form (e.g. *Wed* vs *Wednesday*)

e.g. from [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> Month: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is
>   interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number.

Comment: when i out.print(newPeerdateNtime), it shows as Wed Feb 06 21:11:00 GMT-08:00 2013. Why is it so? :(

Comment: Perhaps you need to specify a timezone ?

Comment: Ahh i think its fine! SQL Server can interpret the date correctly even though the printing of dates is in diff format..:) Thanks Brian Agnew!

Comment: EDIT: OKAY got it again. haha! I finally know how does this SimpleDateFormat works..